# Избавление от вложенных list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Пробую написать код без использования цикла и пользовательских функции для подсчета числа совпадений пар шаров (лотерея) из заданного списка с шарами из каждого розыгрыша.

Результаты step1 и step2 соддерджат вложенные списки из-за чего подсчет статистик не работает. Вопрос как избавиться от вложенных списков?

```
# read CSV to DF
fn = r'D:\work\.data\SO\954414.csv'
draws = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=';',header=0, index_col='draw_id')

bc = (draws.stack().value_counts())    
bc1 = bc.iloc[:12].index

#выбираем игры у которых при пересечение с bc1 совпадает более 1 шара 
mask = draws.T.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & set(bc1))) > 1 
step1 = draws[mask].T.apply(lambda x: set(x) & set(bc1)).to_frame() 

#формируем комбинации по двум шарам из предыдущей выборки 
step2 = step1.apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x,2))).to_frame() 

#аггрегируем данные для step2  
step3 = (step2.apply(lambda x:reduce(operator.concat, x))[0]).values_count()
```

Текущее значение переменной step1

```
array([[{9, 30}],
       [{9, 6, 15}],
    ..
       [{4, 30}],
       [{1, 15}]], dtype=object)
```

Ожидаемый результат для переменной step1

```
array([[9, 30],
       [9, 6, 15],
    ..
       [4, 30],
       [1, 15]], dtype=object)
```

Ожидаемый результат для step3

```
{(23, 32): 10,
 (1, 32): 9,
 (6, 13): 9,
 (6, 32): 9,
 (12, 27): 8,
 (9, 32): 8,
 (8, 22): 8,
 (9, 23): 8,
 (8, 30): 7,
 (1, 13): 7}
```

Исходные данные.

```
draw_id;ball1;ball2;ball3;ball4;ball5;ball6;ball7
1;9;11;17;29;30;33;36
2;5;6;9;11;15;33;28
3;4;5;10;14;20;30;8
4;4;21;22;25;26;36;6
5;1;11;13;17;24;29;36
6;2;17;22;24;27;30;1
7;4;15;26;28;29;35;34
8;12;22;24;26;31;33;2
9;6;9;16;24;33;34;17
10;3;8;12;19;27;31;1
11;4;5;7;9;14;20;25
12;9;20;32;33;35;36;22
13;16;19;23;25;29;32;12
14;6;10;11;17;33;35;15
15;1;5;16;19;22;28;33
16;3;6;7;8;16;29;12
17;1;3;10;19;24;32;23
18;9;25;27;29;33;35;22
19;7;13;17;18;21;34;6
20;7;14;18;20;27;33;28
21;1;3;5;8;22;23;25
22;4;5;13;19;28;34;11
23;3;24;26;32;35;36;14
24;2;7;18;22;30;32;4
25;5;22;28;30;31;33;3
26;1;4;6;28;31;32;13
27;7;10;15;18;23;30;8
28;6;10;12;16;18;19;4
29;9;12;16;21;23;27;3
30;6;15;18;19;25;29;2
31;4;7;22;28;29;30;15
32;3;7;14;18;33;35;29
33;4;14;21;23;28;29;30
34;2;5;9;21;26;27;20
35;1;3;9;11;13;17;27
36;11;13;15;28;32;35;18
37;3;11;16;21;28;35;15
38;1;2;12;13;14;15;6
39;5;10;13;16;18;21;20
40;1;4;18;23;32;36;7
41;6;9;13;17;18;35;23
42;11;13;19;23;24;27;12
43;2;3;8;14;32;35;25
44;1;5;12;14;21;25;9
45;2;4;15;25;28;31;9
46;19;21;23;26;30;35;2
47;11;16;22;23;24;30;8
48;8;9;11;27;30;35;32
49;1;15;22;26;31;32;25
50;3;5;8;12;16;21;7
51;7;8;13;21;22;32;30
52;1;4;8;14;27;30;12
53;2;16;20;22;27;30;21
54;1;5;16;25;27;36;22
55;4;26;28;30;32;33;6
56;5;10;13;18;24;27;29
57;1;4;5;8;22;25;28
58;3;11;24;27;29;34;17
59;1;2;6;9;14;23;32
60;5;10;12;15;24;33;22
61;5;12;15;23;24;32;18
62;2;5;11;13;25;28;10
63;8;13;18;19;27;31;12
64;7;9;11;23;32;34;22
65;2;4;7;15;27;30;26
66;4;12;15;16;17;19;11
67;6;7;9;12;17;19;27
68;12;17;25;27;32;33;36
69;6;19;20;26;27;35;21
70;6;15;21;32;34;35;1
71;4;7;9;10;14;23;26
72;6;21;26;30;31;32;28
73;3;8;13;22;29;31;12
74;6;8;13;15;27;34;5
75;8;13;24;29;31;33;6
76;6;14;17;23;26;32;21
77;4;9;15;16;23;32;13
78;1;8;13;23;27;33;24
79;1;13;16;26;29;32;6
80;9;12;16;22;24;35;32
81;8;9;18;19;23;28;20
82;1;6;7;20;28;29;32
83;8;17;22;25;26;31;11
84;3;11;18;24;26;29;1
85;10;11;13;21;27;30;6
86;2;13;23;25;30;35;29
87;14;16;17;25;29;30;4
88;7;8;12;22;25;31;16
89;16;23;24;27;32;33;19
90;6;16;18;25;27;28;7
91;13;15;17;19;24;32;6
92;1;12;15;19;27;34;36
93;3;6;7;9;18;33;31
94;6;11;12;14;21;29;23
95;8;11;14;15;29;36;22
96;1;9;14;25;30;32;26
97;4;10;25;31;35;36;17
98;9;16;27;32;35;36;23
99;10;21;28;29;31;34;17
100;1;12;13;24;26;33;22
101;2;4;15;18;19;30;8
```

Comment: Что значит избавиться? Не могли бы вы переформулировать вопрос без излишней информации?

Comment: Вы бы сделали минимально воспроизводимый пример и полученный и ожидаемый результат. А то не очень понятно, что вы хотите

Comment: В вопросе отутствуют определения переменных `common`, `bc1` - попробуйте оформить в вопросе минимальный, воспроизводимый пример и проверить его...